# MySQL warnings about max_open_files and table_open_cache

Tags: mysql, logging, warnings

I have a MySQL 5.7 server on Ubuntu 18. When the server starts it writes the following warnings in the error.log:

```
[Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 5000 (requested 7500)
[Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 1745 (requested 2000)
```

Can somebody explain what is causing these warnings (and what I can do to make them go away)?

Comment: "what I can do to make them go away" well increase those values?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how and where to do that?

Comment: will it be reason for mysql crash ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question. The limit for max open files is defined in the systemd script **/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service**:

```
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target
....

LimitNOFILE=5000
```

Increasing the value of LimitNOFILE to 7500 solved both warnings.

Comment: I'm pleased to see that this is **not** the case with my service file (defaults should be coming from the mysql config files, not from Systemd!), but that leaves the same question. PROBABLY, just upping my limits in the mysql config is the answer, but then what is asking for the higher numbers?